# Looking options for xalan TransformerFactoryImpl

Tags: jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser, xalan

I m using SAX based XML parser, things are working fine but I'm getting the following warning message in log

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release 
                                transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

I want to get rid of this, can anybody suggest me other options for `TransformerFactoryImpl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` instead:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory tf =       
        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

How it determines which implementation to load is told in [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance%28%29).

If it is important to keep care that you have exactly same implementation behind the scenes that you are currently using, just set following system property before obtaining TransformerFactory instance. I assume that using same implementation is convenient, as long as you get rid of error message.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",          
                   "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

Comment: Hello @Mikko,

I tried the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory initially but i was getting following exception.

<pre>
Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource :
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource
 at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:366)

</pre><br>

I missed to set system property. Thanks for the help.

Thanks a lot,
Chinmay Pathak